# Guidance on creating a basic search function in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

Still pretty new to Rails and hoping to develop a function on a site enabling a search to be performed of the manner detailed below:

User inputs a search term / phrase (string of words but unlikely to be more than 5 or 6)

String is chopped into its constituent words

Entries in a single model with a description (a single field in the model) are output

Having looked at previous questions on this site, I am aware that there are a number of add-ons which are commonly used for search queries, however, are these needed in such a simple situation?

I was thinking that I could use an SQL command with a number of ANDs to perform this task?
Currently the model is stored within sqlite3, but it is probably going to grow to about 100,000 lines (just 10 fields though) in the near future if this is likely to cause problems?

Finally, is there an easy way to pull out the words of a string automatically for any length of string / up to a certain limit that is unlikely to be exceeded?

Thanks in advance for your time and patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily pull the words from a string with ruby: `'alice bob charlie'.split(/\s+/)` will give you an array with the words.

Then, you can string those words together into an SQL query to find the appropriate records. It don't know about the performance of this solution though... You should definitely test it out to see if there are any performance issues.